# Error while installing multer packages using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am getting the following error while installing the multer package using npm.

```
dicer  *
Severity: high
Crash in HeaderParser in dicer - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wm7h-9275-46v2
No fix available
node_modules/dicer
  busboy  <=0.3.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of dicer
  node_modules/busboy
    multer  <=2.0.0-rc.3
    Depends on vulnerable versions of busboy
    node_modules/multer
3 high severity vulnerabilities
Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

Comment: Which part of the error message are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 9):

you can update **multer** to 1.4.5 as the latest version with `npm i multer@latest` that uses

> busboy@1.0.0

without any vulnerabilities.

Comment: Version 1.4.5 has some bugs which might affect you. You can also install `v1.4.4-lts.1`, it seems to fix the vulnerability met here.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to vulnerability in dicer dependency. Multer will still work, right now no fix is available. Maybe it will be resolved in next update. [Check this GitHub reviewed vulnerability](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wm7h-9275-46v2)

Answer (score 0):

**I am a *novice* and this is not advice on what you should do - I'm just relaying what I did and what the outcome was.**

*This is a duplicate of my post on the same issue, on [GitHub](https://github.com/mscdex/dicer/issues/30#issuecomment-1146029399)*

After deploying my Vuejs3 app a week ago to Firebase, I was prompted to upgrade to the newest version of Firebase Tools (11.0.1) via npm. After doing this, I began experiencing  the problem detailed in [my comment on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1729#issuecomment-1139486497).

Having no other solutions on the table, I decided to uninstall firebase tools (`npm uninstall -g firebase-tools`) and then reinstall the previous version (`npm install -g firebase-tools@10.9.2`).

**BUT**, after first time I did this, I ran `npm audit fix` (not `npm audit fix --force`) and all I got a ton of high severity warnings and problems.

So I decided to once again uninstall firebase tools (`npm uninstall -g firebase-tools`) and then reinstall the previous version (`npm install -g firebase-tools@10.9.2`) and that's it (did NOT run  `npm audit fix`).

I proceeded to `npm run build` and `firebase deploy --only hosting` and it worked just fine.  Definitely NOT a great or long-term solution. Good luck!